# Separate build and run dependencies (in official debs especially)?

Tags: ros, deb, build, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that fuerte introduced the concept for build_depends for stacks. That brings up an interesting point: There's a difference between build and non-build dependencies.

- Is there a plan to separate build deps in general?
- Will build_depends be added to the manifest.xml?

Dependency on libboost1.x-dev, for example, pulls in the entire gcc toolchain which is not strictly necessary for running ros nodes, especially in production.

Is there any plan to seperate ros into lib and dev portions, especially in light of the plan to become FSH compliant;

- [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard layout changes for ROS](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0122.html)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40193/separate-build-and-run-dependencies-(in-official-debs-especially)?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2012-07-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the new prototype of catkin we have separate build and runtime dependencies at the stack level.  There's a thought of merging stack and package concepts together, in which case yes to both...

I suggest that you bring this up on the [ROS buildsystem SIG mailing list](http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Planning/Buildsystem) for discussion.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2